Rolling coin problem: When can we apply torque equation?
This is a problem from Morin (8.22).

Here is my solution, which is wrong according to Morin's answer. (For whatever reason they flagged this question as a homework question, but the problem is deeper here, Obviously, for whatever reason writing torque equation wrt $O$ is incorrect, or there is some other problem, I don't ask you to check my calculations, they are correct and yield the result below, I need to know what is conceptually wrong in this solution)
We consider Angular momentum wrt point O.

$$
\vec{L} = m \vec{R}_c \times \vec{V}_c +\frac{1}{2} m r^2 \vec{\omega}.
$$
where $ \frac{1}{2} m r^2 \vec{\omega}$  is angular momentum wrt COM. Then we write torque equation $$
\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \vec{\Omega} \times \vec{L}=\vec{\tau} = m \vec{\mathcal{ℜ}} \times \vec{g}. 
$$ where $|\vec{\mathcal{ℜ}}|=r \cos \theta$.
No slipping condition gives us $$\omega r = \Omega R$$
$$\vec{\Omega} \times \vec{L} = m \left( \vec{\Omega} \times (\vec{R}_c \times \vec{V}_c) \right) + \frac{1}{2} m r^2 \left( \vec{\Omega} \times \vec{\omega} \right) = m \left( \vec{R}_c (\vec{\Omega} \cdot \vec{V}_c) - \vec{V}_c (\vec{\Omega} \cdot \vec{R}_c) \right) + \frac{1}{2} m r^2 \left( \vec{\Omega} \times \vec{\omega} \right)$$
Further simplifying and using that $|\vec{V}_c| = \Omega \left( R - r \cos \theta \right)$ and projecting this equation along the torque direction, we get an answer that is differnet from Morin's by a factor of $5/4$ next to $r$ $$ \Omega^2 = \frac{g}{\frac{3}{2}R \tan \theta - r \sin \theta}$$
I just don't see where I went wrong. I can write the torque equation wrt point $O$, because that frame of reference is not accelerating. (If you think it's rotating by any chance, it's not). Angular momentum wrt COM is also just $\frac{1}{2} m r^2 \vec{\omega}$. I don't need to provided with the solution given in Morin, I want to know what is wrong with my solution.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
